# The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project asp

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, angular9

**When I try to use command to create component "ng g c new-component" appear this error:**

```
node.exe : The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
En C:\Users\luisfe.moreno\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1: 15 Carácter: 3
+   & "node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" $args
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The generate co...d not be found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

**Angular version**

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.3
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 
... 
Ivy Workspace: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.3
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.3
@angular/cli                 9.0.3
@schematics/angular          9.0.3
@schematics/update           0.900.3
rxjs                         6.5.3
```

**Asp core version:**

```
PM> dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview8-013656 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: Make sure you are inside your project directory.

Comment: You have to run this command from the directory containing the **angular.json** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you execute `ng g c new-component` not from the angular project. Change your current directory to an angular project, the one where `angular.json` is located.

```
cd <path-to-folder-containing-angular.json>
ng g c new-component
```

Comment: thanks  for help me, currently I'm learning angular, what line edit to get solution

Comment: @FelipeMoreno you don't need to modify any files just run `ng g c new-component` from the right place in powershell/cmd. Look into the updated answer, please.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got solution :)